# Python regex not to match http://

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am facing a problem to match and replace certain words, not contained in http://

Present Regex:

```
 http://.*?\s+
```

This matches the pattern `http://www.egg1.com  http://www.egg2.com`

I need a regex to match certain words contained outside the http://

Example:

```
"This is a sample. http://www.egg1.com and http://egg2.com. This regex will only match 
 this egg1 and egg2 and not the others contained inside http:// "

 Match: egg1 egg2

 Replaced: replaced1 replaced2
```

Final Output :

```
 "This is a sample. http://www.egg1.com and http://egg2.com. This regex will only 
  match this replaced1 and replaced2 and not the others contained inside http:// "
```

QUESTION:
Need to match certain patterns (as in example : egg1 egg2) unless they are part of http:// .Do not match egg1 and egg2 if they are present within http://

Comment: In other words: You want to match certain patterns (in your example *egg1* and *egg2*) **unless** they are part of an URL?

Comment: The way you state the question, it doesn't really matter, whether the match comes from the URL or not. What is it you actually want to match?

Comment: @Ferdinand Yes..you are right.. If egg1 and egg2 are inside an http:// do not match it.

Comment: So, in “`http://foo.co.uk`” you want the `co`?

Comment: He wants to find "Google" in "Google can be found at `http://www.google.com`", skipping the "google" within the URL.

Comment: Text after http:// isn't "contained inside" it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution I can think of is to form a combined pattern for HTTP-URLs and your pattern, then filter the matches accordingly:

```
import re

t = "http://www.egg1.com http://egg2.com egg3 egg4"

p = re.compile('(http://\S+)|(egg\d)')
for url, egg in p.findall(t):
  if egg:
    print egg
```

prints:

```
egg3
egg4
```

---

**UPDATE:** To use this idiom with `re.sub()`, just supply a filter function:

```
p = re.compile(r'(http://\S+)|(egg(\d+))')

def repl(match):
    if match.group(2):
        return 'spam{0}'.format(match.group(3))
    return match.group(0)

print p.sub(repl, t)
```

prints:

```
http://www.egg1.com http://egg2.com spam3 spam4
```

Comment: Since I will be using re.sub to replace the matched words, Can I do the same you did with re.sub?

Comment: @Ferdinana Is it possible to use the filter functions with a matched group(like spam1 spam2)..updated in question..

Comment: Yes, of course.  You can do anything you like in the filter function plus you can nest grouping parantheses in the regex.  I updated my answer accordingly.  I guess you can figure it out by yourself from here on?

Answer (score 2):

This will not capture `http://...`:

```
(?:http://.*?\s+)|(egg1)
```

Comment: You should mention that it would require the usage of `group(1)` to get the correct value, and that it will still return matches for the URLs, just with the value for group 1 being `None`.

Comment: @JAB Yeah, you are right. I just made an assumption that he knows how regexps work in general :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to precede your pattern by a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<!http://)egg[0-9]
```

In this regular expression, every time the regex engine finds a pattern matching `egg[0-9]` it will look back to verify if the preceding patters *do not match* `http://`. A negative lookbehind assertion starts with `(?<!` and ends with `)`. Everything between these delimiters should not precede the following pattern and will not be included in the result.

How to use it in your case:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('(?<!http://)egg[0-9]')
>>> a = "Example: http://egg1.com egg2 http://egg3.com egg4foo"
>>> regex.findall(a)
['egg2', 'egg4']
```

Comment: @Ferdinand yes, you are right. Apparently, the lookbehind assertion is not the right tool for this job :)

Answer (score -2):

Extending brandizzi's answer, I would just change his regex to this:

```
(?<!http://[\w\._-]*)(egg1|egg2)
```

Comment: It's a trap: Look-behind require fixed-width patterns, so your example won't compile.

Comment: have you even tried this? `sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`.

Comment: My bad, I tried it with a .Net regex utility, not a Python one.