# How does a whitesapce matched by a positive lookahead assertion appears in the final matched string in Python regex?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6859763/287976), I created this Python regular expression to match any `egg` substring followed by a digit that is not part of a URL preceded by `http://`:

```
>>> r = re.compile('(?:\s(?!http://\S*))egg\d')
```

Then I applied it to the following string:

```
>>> a = "a egg1 http://egg2.com egg3 http://www.egg4.org egg5"
```

The result is:

```
>>> r.findall(a)
[' egg1', ' egg3', ' egg5']
```

The regular expression is not correct for a lot of other problems but one bugged more: why does the whitespace appears in the result? Since I used a lookahead assertion like `(?:\s...)`, shouldn't  it be take out of the resulting strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:...)` isn't a lookahead assertion, it's simply a non-capturing pair of parens (i.e. what is matched by the sub-regex inside doesn't do into its own group, it only exists for precedence). `(?=...)` is a lookahead assertion.

Answer (score 1):

`(?:` is not a lookahead, but a non-capturing group. As such, it doesn't create its own capture, but it is part of the full match.